# I need to type "exit" after running a c program to get the output

Tags: c, command-prompt

I need to type "exit" after I try to run my c program from command line. After the .exe, when I hit return key, I need to type exit to get the output.
Structure of programs :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, r1, r2, r5, r10, r50, r100;
    printf("Enter amount :");
    scanf(" %d \n", &a);
    r100 = a / 100;
    a = a - (r100*100);
    r50 = a / 50;
    a = a - (r50*50);
    r10 = a / 10;
    a = a - (r10*10);
    r5 = a / 5;
    a = a - (r5*5);
    r2 = a / 2;
    a = a - (r2*2);
    r1 = a;
    printf("Rs100 denominations : %d", r100);
    printf("\nRs50 denominations : %d", r50);
    printf("\nRs10 denominations : %d", r10);
    printf("\nRs5 denominations : %d", r5);
    printf("\nRs2 denominations : %d", r2);
    printf("\nRs1 denominations : %d", r1);
    return 0;
}
```

Windows8.1, 64-bit..
compiling command >> gcc ykc1ij.c -o ykc1ij.exe ..
running >> ykc1ij.exe

Comment: That's the structure of every C program, basically ... paste some code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: where's your code ? show some work you've done......

Comment: Perhaps you are missing some call to `fflush` (e.g. because your `printf` format control strings do not *end* with `\n`). But we can't guess unless you show your C source code, and give your operating system, your compiler, your compilation command. So please *edit your question to improve it*.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you'll better *end* every `printf` format string with `\n`. Read [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (and more generally, take the habit of reading the documentation of every function that you are using). You should test the result of `scanf` (it returns the number of *successfully* scanned items, or -1 on error), so:

```
printf("Enter amount :\n");
if (scanf(" %d \n", &a)<1) 
  { perror("scanf failure"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You'll need to `#include <stdlib.h>` for [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html).

Otherwise I suggest to initialize every variable (it is a good habit to have, since it makes your program runs more reproducible; a good optimizing compiler would remove the useless initializations):

```
int a=0, r1=0, r2=0;
```

<sup>BTW, I dislike the variable names you are using. They are not very meaningful to a human reader.</sup>

At last, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g`), improve your code till you get no warnings, and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: As a note, `errno` isn't set by `scanf` for matching failures and EOF on POSIX systems, and isn't set at all in standard C.